# \printglossary not working locally on Overleaf Community server

Tags: glossaries

I have local installation of the Overleaf Community Version. The defined acronyms are recognized - get printed by \acrshort{} and \acrfull{}, but the glossary won't get printed even if I use the very example for glossaries from the Overleaf documentation.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newacronym{gcd}{GCD}{Greatest Common Divisor}

\newacronym{lcm}{LCM}{Least Common Multiple}

\begin{document}
Given a set of numbers, there are elementary methods to compute 
its \acrlong{gcd}, which is abbreviated \acrshort{gcd}. This process 
is similar to that used for the \acrfull{lcm}.

\clearpage

\printglossary[type=\acronymtype]

\end{document}
```

I've cleared the cache, the package is installed, file is in the root folder of the project. This code works on the web version but not locally.

Comment: Exactly how are you running this? From a webbrowser? It runs just fine for me on the command line under `latexmk -pdf` (which is also the standard in Overleaf)

Comment: Yes, I am using the Overleaf web GUI.By web version I mean on the overleaf.com server.

Comment: Also on your `Overleaf Community server`? You need to figure out exactly what is being done when compiling. Running `pdflatex` is not enough (which is why `latexmk` is used).

Comment: I figured out that after generating the pdf I need to manually do `makeglossaries output.acn` and then generate the pdf once more.

Comment: That is why I asked **exactly what do you do to compile** here. `latexmk` runs `makeglossaries` automatically. I guess now we known you're compiling in a different manner than the overleaf webinterface.

Comment: No. I am sorry if my description is confusing.
- I compiled the document using the web GUI of the Overleaf. The glossary is not printed out.
- I digged in the files generated by overleaf and found that the .acn was missing. I tried generating it manually which worked.
- Then re-generated the pdf using Overleaf GUI again, the glosarry was printed ok.

Answer (score 0):

I hit the very same problem. My setup: local Overleaf 3.2.2 instance installed via the toolkit. I found a workaround on [docker overleaf github](https://github.com/overleaf/docker-image/issues/6#issuecomment-282931678). I tried both variants. Both worked.  I'm copying them here:

1. Configuration for each project: Create `latexmkrc` file in the project, add this content:

```perl
# Fix generating of glossaries
# Source: https://github.com/overleaf/docker-image/issues/6#issuecomment-282931678
add_cus_dep('glo', 'gls', 0, 'makeglo2gls');
sub makeglo2gls {
    system("makeindex -s '$_[0]'.ist -t '$_[0]'.glg -o '$_[0]'.gls '$_[0]'.glo");
}

add_cus_dep('acn', 'acr', 0, 'makeacn2acr');
sub makeacn2acr {
    system("makeindex -s \"$_[0].ist\" -t \"$_[0].alg\" -o \"$_[0].acr\" \"$_[0].acn\"");
}
```

Clear all cached files and recompile.

2. For the whole instance: enter the docker image (`bin/shell` in the toolkit's directory). Run: `mkdir -p /usr/local/lib/latexmk`. Create the file `latexmkrc` in this directory with the same content as in the point above. Remember that the container is ephemeral, so you have to save the new container. See the [documentation for toolkit](https://github.com/overleaf/toolkit/blob/master/doc/ce-upgrading-texlive.md#saving-your-changes). Clear all the generated files and recompile.